# How to remove order item with Ajax from Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I've been trying to remove an order item from my cart view with Ajax... For the moment, if I press Delete button, the order item is removed from db, but not from the view and my code below does not work(I have very little understanding of ajax/jquery, so maybe an explantion a little more detailed would help):

controller.rb:

```
def destroy
@order_line.destroy
respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to :action => "show", :id => current_order_id }
  format.js
end
if last_order_item?(@order)
  @order.destroy 
  redirect_to books_url
end
end
```

view.html.erb:

```
<% @order.order_lines.order(:book_id).each do |line| %>
    <div class="order_line_row" id = "orderline-<%= line.id%>">
        <div class="book_details">
            <% if File.file?("#{Rails.root}/app/assets/images/#{line.book.image}") %>
                <%= image_tag line.book.image, class: "card-img-top", alt: "test image" %>
            <% else %>
                <%= image_tag "images.jpeg", class: "card-img-top", alt: "test image" %>
            <% end %>
            <h5 class="product-name"><%= line.book.title %></h5>
            <%= link_to 'Delete book', order_line_path(line.id), method: :delete, remote: true, class: "btn btn-primary" %> 
        </div>

        <div class="quantity">
            <%= form_for(line) do |f| %>
                <%= f.label :qty %></br>
                <%= f.number_field :qty, in: 1...line.book.stock %>
                <%= f.submit "Update", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
            <% end %>
        </div>

        <div class="price">Price</br><%= line.subtotal_price %></div>

    </div>
    <hr>
<% end %>
```

destroy.js.rb:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#orderline-<%= @line.id %>').remove();
})
```

Thanks for your time...

Comment: Are you using `turbolinks`? If so, you might try `$(document).on "turbolinks:load"` instead of `$(document).ready` as discussed in the [docs](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#turbolinks).

Comment: @jvillian, I've tried that but it's not working.

Comment: I also noticed you're trying to do string interpolation here: `'#orderline-<%= @line.id %>'` using single quotes. But it only works with double quotes. Also try: `"#orderline-<%= @line.id %>"`.

Comment: String interpolation looks like `"Ordered by #{ @order.name}"'. @himn is just injecting Ruby code that will create part of the Javascript. The Javascript itself will run fine with single quotes or double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Your destroy.js.erb should just be:

```
    $('#orderline-<%= @line.id %>').remove();
```

The `.ready()` function only runs after the DOM is loaded. You want to change an element that has already been loaded.

There are couple of problems with the `destroy` controller method, too.

```
    def destroy

      # Add next line to create the @order_line object
      @order_line = OrderLine.find(params[:id])

      @order_line.destroy
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to :action => "show", :id => current_order_id }
        format.js
      end

      # None of this code will execute because the response 
      # has already been rendered. This needs to be before respond_to
      if last_order_item?(@order)
        @order.destroy 
        redirect_to books_url
      end
    end
```